# Edited entities of xcdatamodeld but get Crash - Core Data in swift

Tags: swift, sqlite, core-data

I renamed some `Entities` of `name.xcdatamodeld` and delete other `Entities` and then I deleted app from simulator and restarted it but when I run the app get me bellow crash:

```
PortalApp[4672:94749] [error] error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C094CF3E-7181-40AC-A524-3F8A8DFF4435/data/Containers/Data/Application/4B52E366-DB37-4E7C-AB65-DA7B4D2B3BB3/Documents/MyDB.sqlite options:(null) ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "(null)" UserInfo={metadata={
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 866;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
        Degrees = <2b0631df 5061efec 22ec7f0a dcf7e24f b77c2c73 2f8b9e31 97232c2d 17e05d98>;
        ShortMajorTBL = <9d0263c5 f17cc305 bff7b776 df4a4318 62036151 4d526781 2a21fdde c33a28f1>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "2AC92D09-DE75-40EA-827A-3217C64A301E";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store} with userInfo dictionary {
    metadata =     {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 866;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
            Degrees = <2b0631df 5061efec 22ec7f0a dcf7e24f b77c2c73 2f8b9e31 97232c2d 17e05d98>;
            ShortMajorTBL = <9d0263c5 f17cc305 bff7b776 df4a4318 62036151 4d526781 2a21fdde c33a28f1>;
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
            ""
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "2AC92D09-DE75-40EA-827A-3217C64A301E";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    };
    reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";
}
```

I deleted `Degrees table` and renamed `ShortMajorTBL` to `FiltersTBL`.

I cleared project and build it but get me above crash yet.

Answer (score 0):

Its a classic case, when the store was created the state of entities is different then the current state of entities and thats what its complaining about.

There are various ways in which you can resolve it.

- If developing an app, deleting the app from simulator/device might help.
- As you are in development phase the easiest way is to get the path to
  the persistent store. Once you have the path go to that path in the 
  finder and delete the 3 sqlite files(with extensions .sqlite,
  .slite-shm, .sqlite-wal) which are created by Core Data as a parts of
  the store. You can even destroy the store programmatically, but be sure to remove the store destruction code after the errors go away.
- If your app is already on appstore and you are developing a new
  version, then you should look towards migration, as the above points might provide you temporary solutions.